# Python: Iteratively run a set of similar definitions

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a script that runs a series of definitions in it that looks like this:

```
def object1 (row):
    if row['Item'] == 'object 1':
        return row['Qty']
    else:
        return 0

df['object name 1'] = df.apply(lambda row: object1(row),axis=1)


def object2 (row):
    if row['Item'] == 'object2':
        return row['Qty']
    else:
        return 0

df['object name 2'] = df.apply(lambda row: object2(row),axis=1)


def object3 (row):
    if row['Item'] == 'object3':
        return row['Qty']
    else:
        return 0
df['object name 3'] = df.apply(lambda row: object3(row),axis=1)
```

There are a handful of these. They define a formula given certain parameters in the excel sheet. Just trying to clean up the script a bit. Is there a way to run these definitions in one large command (for instance, a for loop or some such)? And just have it change the names as it runs through them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.loc` and a pattern like this:

```
object_names = ['object 1', 'object 2', 'object 3']
column_names = ['object name 1', 'object name 2', 'object name 3']
for obj_name, col_name in zip(object_names, column_names):
    df[col_name] = df.loc[df['Item']==obj_name, 'Qty']

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

The code above allows you to specify exactly which values in `df['Item']` that you want to look for, and allows for customization with the column names.

If you just want to iterate over all values in `df['Item']`, and only need generic column names, you can use something along the lines of:

```
for item_name in df['Item'].unique():
    col_name = '{} Column'.format(item_name)
    df[col_name] = df.loc[df['Item']==item_name, 'Qty']

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```